# Listing all subsets of size $k$ of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ with just $C \binom{n}{k}$ operations

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I was wondering if it is possible to list all subsets of size $k$ of the set $\{1,...,n\}$ by performing at most $C \binom{n}{k}$ operations for a fixed constant $C$.

I did find a way to compute these subsets more efficiently than by just listing all subsets of size $k$. An example is starting with $[1,...,k]$, increasing the element with index $k$ until it reaches $n$ and once it does going back until we reach the first index that can still be increased (index $k-i$ can never exceed $n-i$, e.g. the second-to-last element can never be bigger than $n-1$, since the last has to be higher). Then increase that index and 'reset' all values after. By just repeating this process we should find all subsets and after writing some code it seems to be successful.

It seems to me that the amount of operations necessary for this algorithm is not in the order ("big-Oh") of $\binom{n}{k}$ however, since every time your last value reaches $n$ you need to perform an amount of operations in the order of $k$ to 'reset' your list, and the amount of times you need to do this should be in the order of $\binom{n}{k}$, so I think the total amount of operations is in the order of $k\binom{n}{k}$.

So my question is if I am indeed right in this, and if it is actually possible to do this in at most $C \binom{n}{k}$ operations.

Comment: Listing $\binom nk$ subsets of size $k$ can of course not be done faster than with $k\binom nk$ output operations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you for your comment. You are of course right, I guess I am looking for order $\binom{n}{k}$ operations ignoring output operations